# When dragging and dropping a file, the dataTransfer.items property is undefined in Firefox and IE, but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

When dragging/dropping a file onto an element, Chrome populates the drop event's [dataTransfer.items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535861(v=vs.85).aspx) array with an object referencing the file being dropped. Firefox and IE do not. These browsers all populate the dataTransfer.files property.

```
function doDrop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();      
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files //All browsers have this property
  var items = e.dataTransfer.items //Only Chrome has this property
}
```

**So why the difference in browsers? Is Chrome right? Is IE and Firefox behind? Do any "formal" documentation or sources explain this?**

Run this [File Drop Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/42bilYthqXqkcyGM4g1m) in various browsers to see the difference.

Comment: `e.dataTransfer.files` does not work in Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to HTML5.1 Specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#the-datatransfer-interface)

```
interface DataTransfer {
  attribute DOMString dropEffect;
  attribute DOMString effectAllowed;

  [SameObject] readonly attribute DataTransferItemList items;

  void setDragImage(Element image, long x, long y);

  /* old interface */
  [SameObject] readonly attribute DOMString[] types;
  DOMString getData(DOMString format);
  void setData(DOMString format, DOMString data);
  void clearData(optional DOMString format);
  [SameObject] readonly attribute FileList files;
};
```

Note that the `files` attribute is in the "old interface" section, while `items` is in the current interface.

So it seems that Chrome is ahead of the curve.  It is implementing both the old interface and the current one, while the other browsers are implementing only the old interface.